# Скачивание файла и редирект

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день.

Подскажите, как сделать при нажатии на ссылку, чтоб выполнялось два действия - скачивания прайс-листа и переход на другой сайт.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, например, у Вас есть файл, размещенный по адресу: site.ru/file.doc

В шаблоне есть ссылка, в ней прописываете свойство перехода на новую строку:

```
<a href="site.ru/file.doc" target="_blank" onclick="return location.href = 'http://www.сайт_на_который_нужно_перейти.ru/'" ></a>
```

В итоге пользователю откроется новое окно со скачкой файла, а в текущем окне произойдет переход на нужную страницу.

Comment: Спасибо все работает!

Comment: Всегда рад помочь :)

Comment: можно еще вопрос :)

Скажите, а можно сделать без открытия второй вкладки `target="_blank"`?


Заранее Вам спасибо!

Comment: По сути скачивание файла - это переход по новой странице. А браузер уже сам определяет, что это файл и предлагает скачать его.
А сделать последовательный переход по ссылка нельзя. Так как нельзя в одном окне перейти по двум ссылка одновременно.

Возможно есть способы перехвата события скачивания файла, т.е. пользователь нажал скачать файл, потом вылетел попам с выбором места сохранения. И когда пользователь нажал "Сохранить" и вот тут должна произойти обработка события нажатия этой кнопки и переход по нужной ссылке.

Comment: А событие этого окна скорее не получится перехватить, так как это системное окно ОС(windows). И jquery не имеет доступ к нему.